# vscode vim extension remmaped UP and DOWN keys not working when being held down

Tags: visual-studio-code

Information about my system:

```
Version: 1.41.0
OS: Darwin x64 18.7.0
```

Using the `vscodevim` extension v1.12.2 with these settings:

```
    "vim.easymotion": true,
    "vim.sneak": true,
    "vim.incsearch": true,
    "vim.useSystemClipboard": true,
    "vim.useCtrlKeys": true,
    "vim.hlsearch": true,
    "vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
      {
        "before": ["k", "j"],
        "after": ["<Esc>"]
      }
```

My problem:

When I want to scroll DOWN or UP quickly by holding down "j" or "k" it freezes. It down up or down one line, then stops.

I can hold down the UP/DOWN arrow keys just fine, but for some reason the "j" and "k" keys aren't reacting the way I want them to when I hold them down.

Answer (score 9):

I found a solution. First, run

```
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

then restart vscode.

Comment: Simple and perfect answer!

Comment: I have been searching for this. Thank you, so much :)